# WP8 Create a second tile causing App exit

Tags: windows-phone-8, flip, tile

To add a second Flip tile, I use the following code at the first time loading of MainPage.xaml
                if the tile doesn't exist, then....

```
            ShellTileData tileData = this.CreateFlipTileData(idx);
            ShellTile.Create(tileUri, tileData, true);
```

The tile is created successfully, but the issue is the App will exit, of course, if user start the app again, it will be fine. Just wondering it is not a good experience, is there a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to stop the your app from exiting when a new secondary tile is created.  The best thing to do is be prepared for when the user presses the Back button to step backwards into your app.

Also, it's good to note that updating an existing tile will NOT cause the app to exit, only the creation of new tiles.